# Why is a "forwarded" event not raised when assigning a method group but is when assigning a delegate?

Tags: c#

Given the following code:

```
public delegate void Signal();

public static class SignalExtensions
{
    public static void SafeInvoke(this Signal signal)
    {
        Signal copy = signal;
        if (copy != null)
        {
            copy();
        }
    }
}

public class RootEventSource
{
    public event Signal RootEvent;

    public void Raise()
    {
        this.RootEvent.SafeInvoke();
    }
}

public class EventForwarder
{
    private readonly RootEventSource rootEventSource;

    public EventForwarder(RootEventSource rootEventSource)
    {
        this.rootEventSource = rootEventSource;

        // this is the critical part
        this.rootEventSource.RootEvent 
             += () => this.AnotherEvent.SafeInvoke();
    }

    public event Signal AnotherEvent;

    // just an example of another method which is using the root event source
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.rootEventSource.ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rootEventSource = new RootEventSource();
        var eventForwarder = new EventForwarder(rootEventSource);

        eventForwarder.AnotherEvent += HandleAnotherEvent;

        rootEventSource.Raise();

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void HandleAnotherEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("received AnotherEvent");
    }
}
```

This results in the output:

```
received AnotherEvent
done
```

---

Now I make a slight change to the implementation of `EventForwarder` to use a method group for forwarding the event:

```
public EventForwarder(RootEventSource rootEventSource)
{
    this.rootEventSource = rootEventSource;
    this.rootEventSource.RootEvent += this.AnotherEvent.SafeInvoke;
}
```

The output becomes:

```
done
```

So `AnotherEvent` is *not raised*.

---

Until now i would have considered the two lines:

```
this.rootEventSource.RootEvent += this.AnotherEvent.SafeInvoke;
this.rootEventSource.RootEvent += () => this.AnotherEvent.SafeInvoke();
```

as being equivalent. It seems they're not.

So what is the difference? Plus why is the event not being raised?

---

PS: while usually R# suggests to replace `() => this.AnotherEvent.SafeInvoke();` by `this.AnotherEvent.SafeInvoke` it doesn't do so here. So apparently it knows that it should not do it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign a method group to event like this:

```
this.rootEventSource.RootEvent += this.AnotherEvent.SafeInvoke;
```

you in fact create a delegate from method `SignalExtensions.SafeInvoke` which as a parameter takes your `this.AnotherEvent`delegate object. Since it is initially `null`, you create a delegate with `null` parameter. This `null` value will of course never change, since delegates are immutable.

If you want to forward an event you should maybe do it like this:

```
public class EventForwarder
{
    private readonly RootEventSource rootEventSource;

    public EventForwarder(RootEventSource rootEventSource)
    {
        this.rootEventSource = rootEventSource;
    }

    public event Signal AnotherEvent
    {
        add { this.rootEventSource.RootEvent += value; }
        remove { this.rootEventSource.RootEvent -= value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes of course this makes perfect sense... Thank you! `() => ` will behave differently since it creates an anonymous delegate which will only evaluate `this.rootEventSource` when it is actually executed.